# Photon Eclipse JEE doesn't launch

Tags: eclipse, lombok, eclipse-photon

In order get the lombok working, After looking into it so much I added a line to the eclipse.ini. But now the eclipse jee photon doesn't launch at all even after deleting the line.

Instead it shows a message like this:

[image]

The eclipse configuration contains:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.5.0.v20180512-1130.jar
--launcher.library C:\Users\Vishwa\.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.700.v20180518-1200
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
-showsplash
org.eclipse.epp.package.common
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Dosgi.dataAreaRequiresExplicitInit=true
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Declipse.p2.max.threads=10
-Domph.update.url=http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest
-Doomph.redirection.index.redirection=index:/->http://git.eclipse.org/c/oomph/org.eclipse.oomph.git/plain/setups/
-javaagent:lombok.jar
```

I added this line

> -Xbootclasspath/a:lombok.jar

What do I do?..Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @Mr.T the configuration and the problem causing line has been added to my post...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most bruteforce solution worked for me.

I couldn't uninstall it because I didn't find eclipse in the control panel programs to remove. So I re-installed the eclipse jee developer from the eclipse.exe again.

Now the eclipse launches.